# Using An Array Inside A Class

Tags: c#, arrays, class, initialization

I am trying to initialize an array that is inside a class.
I am getting the "object reference is not set to an instance of an object" error.

Here's my NPC class:

```
namespace EngineTest
{
    public class npcs
    {
      public int tileX, tileY, layerZ;
      public int textureX, textureY;
      public string ID;
      public string state;
      public int direction; //0 = south, 1= west, 2 = north, 3= east
      public int moveLimitTimer;
      public int animationCurrentFrame;
      public int animationResetTimer;

      public pathPotentials[, ,] pathPotential; (this is the array)
    }
}
```

Here is the pathPotentials Class

```
namespace EngineTest
{

public class npcs
{
    public int tileX, tileY, layerZ;
    public int textureX, textureY;
    public string ID;
    public string state;
    public int direction; //0 = south, 1= west, 2 = north, 3= east
    public int moveLimitTimer;
    public int animationCurrentFrame;
    public int animationResetTimer;

    public pathPotentials[, ,] pathPotential = new pathPotentials[Program.newMapWidth, Program.newMapHeight, Program.newMapLayers];
}
}
```

I tried to initialize it by this code:

```
        for (z = 0; z < Program.newMapLayers; z++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < Program.newMapWidth; x++)
            {
                for (y = 0; y < Program.newMapHeight; y++)
                {
                    if(Program.tileNpcs[x, y, z].npcs.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Program.tileNpcs[x, y, z].npcs[0].pathPotential[Program.newMapWidth, Program.newMapHeight, Program.newMapLayers] = new pathPotentials();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work. What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to initialise the array. i.e. int[] ints = new int[2]; Or in your case pathPotentials[] PathPotentials = new pathPotentials[no of elements];

Comment: You should really consider using `List<T>` instead of that many nested arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# (and a lot of programming languages of this type), arrays have a fixed length. In C#, arrays are stored as an object, with a set of values. Assigning to an element in an array is like altering a field of an object - you need to define the array explicitly first. If you don't define it explicitly, C# doesn't know how much memory to assign the array, which can cause a lot of problems when structuring memory.

You declare a 3-dimensional array, but you don't define it:

```
public pathPotentials[, ,] pathPotential;
```

What you need is something like this:

```
public pathPotentials[, ,] pathPotential = new pathPotentials[Program.newMapWidth, Program.newMapHeight, Program.newMapLayers];
```

This tells C# exactly how big to make your array.

However, this does not allow you to change the size of the array once it is declared (at least without clearing it by redefining it). If you need the size to change at runtime, then C# provides a class List, which takes a generic parameter (which in this case is fairly complex, for a 3D grid). You can declare something like this with Lists like so:

```
public List<List<List<pathPotentials>>> pathPotential = new List<List<List<pathPotentials>>>();
```

This gives you a nested list of lists of lists. The innermost list might be z, the outermost x. To get data from this, you can specify an inex, but you can no longer use [x,y,z] as the notation, and must instead use [x][y][z], as you are accessing a list to get another list item, and then accessing that list to get a second list item, and then accessing that one to get your object.

Hopefully, this has helped you to understand what went wrong, why your code doesn't work, and how you might fix it.

Comment: Edward Kay-Coles thank you for your reply. It's ok for me that the array is not dynamic. I am using a fixed map size.
I already tried this with lists. (Actually a list within an array, and it worked great)
But this is a real time 2D engine and Lists are slowing down the realtime renderer.

Comment: There are different types of lists for different purposes. The most common are List and LinkedList. Lists can be used essentially like arrays, and accessing elements takes constant time. However, to add or remove elements, the index must be changed on all elements after, making that O(n) time cost. For LinkedList, it's the opposite. Adding and removing elements takes constant time, while accessing elements is O(n). You want to pick the datatype to fit your usage. For anything fixed size, don't even go near lists.

Answer (score 0):

the code is bound to give you the error, since before initializing you are referencing a particular item of array. instead of your statement:

```
Program.tileNpcs[x, y, z].npcs[i].pathPotential[Program.newMapWidth, Program.newMapHeight, Program.newMapLayers] = new pathPotentials();
```

You should have it this way:

```
Program.tileNpcs[x, y, z].npcs[i].pathPotential = new pathPotentials[Program.newMapWidth, Program.newMapHeight, Program.newMapLayers];
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pawa Rai but it doesn't work that way either.
I get this error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'EngineTest.pathPotentials[*,*,*]' to 'EngineTest.pathPotentials"

Comment: StaWho thanks for the advice. But I tried it with the list and the performance became an issue. I need the speed of arrays. It is a real time 2D game engine and Lists drop the FPS down like half.

Comment: Pawa Rai, I did what you said but I am still getting the same error.
The array's content is always null.

Comment: hey dear, please check this link http://www.functionx.com/csharp/arrays/Lesson03.htm. the statement that I wrote just creates the array, you also need to initialize each and every element of array as in: Program.tileNpcs[x, y, z].npcs[i].pathPotential[0,0,0] = new pathPotential();